# What´s the right way to create relationship in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

When defining models should I create the id and foreign key or let Sequelize do it?

from the documentation:

```
var User = this.sequelize.define('user', {/* attributes */})
  , Company = this.sequelize.define('company', {/* attributes */});

User.belongsTo(Company); // Will add companyId to user
```

If I want to display all users within a company do I need to add a

```
Company.hasMany(User);
```

or is only needed in the User model?

also I tried to exclude the foreign key

```
attributes: {
    exclude: ['CompanyId']
}
```

and it magically returns the data with companyId (camelCase)